# How to make pylint report unused return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

To the following code:

```
"""Test with unused return value"""

from typing import List

def sorted_int_list(values: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """Returns a new, sorted list"""
    return sorted(values)

def main() -> None:
    """Ignoring value returned by sorted_int_list"""
    values: List[int] = [3, 1, 2]
    sorted_int_list(values) # Should create some kind or error
    print(values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`pylint` says:

```
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10
```

However I would like to have it report the unused return value of `sorted_int_list`. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a **dynamic** language, **static analysis tools** can not know whether the function has a return value. such as:

```
def foo(a):
    if a>0 return 42
    else: pass #do nothing, and not return if a <= 0
```

static analysis tools **cant** help you solve the logic problem.

Related discussion:https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/647

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense of course. In my actual code base, everything is annotated with (return) types, so I just updated the code in my question accordingly.

Comment: This answer isn't valid since late 2017; the example `foo()` function is statically caught by pylint's `inconsistent-return-statements` checker nowadays: <http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/1.8.html>. I'd still like to get return-value-not-used warnings for relevant functions!

Comment: @JohanWalles FYI I've created a pylint featuer request for this: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/7935 . See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785720/python-prevent-discarding-of-the-function-return-value